# Error while building Qt from source code on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, makefile, configure

I want to be able to debug into qt source code so i started compiling the latest Qt version 5.8 on my MAC.
I followed the instructions on Qt webpage about building it. But this is what i get after running configure.

> ../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/configure -prefix
>   /Users/userName/qt-install-5.8 0 -opensource -debug-and-release
>   + cd qtbase
>   + /Users/userName/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/configure -top-level -prefix /Users/username/qt-install-5.8 0 -opensource -debug-and-release
>
> This is the Qt Open Source Edition.
>
> You are licensed to use this software under the terms of the GNU
>   Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3. You are also licensed
>   to use this software under the terms of the GNU General Public License
>   (GPL) version 2.
>
> Type 'L' to view the GNU Lesser General Public License version 3. Type
>   'G' to view the GNU General Public License version 2. Type 'yes' to
>   accept this license offer. Type 'no' to decline this license offer.
>
> Do you accept the terms of either license? yes
>
> Preparing build tree... Creating qmake...
>   ............................................................................................Done.
>
> ERROR: Invalid command line parameter '0'.

I don't understand the last line. I was trying to do a shadow build by creating a new folder for build. I also specified the install directory while running config above. After running config, these are the files that got created in my build folder.

config.cache    config.log  qtbase

Does this look correct.?

I am a newbie to MAC platform but i've completed compiling QT from sources on windows & linux.

When i run make, this is what i got

> make 
>   make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> ../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/configure -prefix
>   /Users/userName/qt-install-5.8 0 -opensource -debug-and-release + cd
>   qtbase + /Users/userName/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/configure
>   -top-level -prefix /Users/username/qt-install-5.8 0 -opensource -debug-and-release

Looks like you've got typos in several places there.  instead of "qt-install-5.8.0" you've got "qt-install-5.8 0", which is getting interpreted by the shell as two different arguments ("qt-install-5.8" and "0"), and the configure script is rightly complaining that "0" is not a valid argument.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Friesner. I must admit that was a stupid mistake and thanks for your time.